# Magento 2 table rate works on cart page but not on checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, table-rates

When I check the shipping via table rate for products ordered in the cart page in my magento 2.3.4 site, it comes out fine  but on the checkout page, I get the errors in the image below.
[image: table rate not working]

I have reviewed the table rates and the configuration , all  checks out fine. the cart rules are all fine.

In the checkout page, when I insert the post code and the rest of the address fields, I keep getting the same error for both the FLAT RATE and TABLE RATE.

I need your assistance.

Comment: need help please

Comment: I noticed that when I go to cart page after the order has been placed, then move to checkout... the table rate works fine but when I jump straight to checkout page [ignoring cart page] after order has been placed, I get the errors above

Answer (score 0):

The cart page does not have shipping details.

Have you enabled the proper shipping rates from magento admin?

Comment: the cart page has the shipping country, state, city and postal code/zip which are all configured to work with table rates and like i mentioned, they all work fine on cart page.